# Downloading a CSV opens up in Web Browser not on a Microsoft Excel

Tags: php, cakephp, csv

I am using CakePHP on performing this code:

View File

```
<?php
   if (isset($csv_filename)) {
      header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$csv_filename");
   }
?>
<?=$csv?>
```

When I run this page and download the file(Open With), it is opening up on a web browser such as Google Chrome or Firefox. I wanted this file to be opened using 
[image]

**My expected output should be like this:**

[image]

Actually, everything was working fine before since we migrated to CakePHP 2.2.2.

Any thoughts on this, your help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Add a header telling the browser what mimetype this is, like so;

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8')
```

Comment: Doesn't matter, just do it before you output anything to browser

Comment: @igorpan still not working. The download box looks still like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/kimyE.png

Comment: Your screenshot above shows "Which is a Chrome HTML Document" - that means you have, nett, not done anything different than the first image in the question

Comment: @AD7six nope, I already added the header above, but still it's not working.

Comment: doing something and doing something right are not the same thing. Compare your 3 screenshots, and it should be evident that you're still serving the csv file as html. Btw Cake has a [mechanism for sending files](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cake-response-file) ([for older versions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/media-view.html)) built in - you aught to be using that rather than doing it the php way.

Answer (score 1):

To make a file download as a CSV setup your routing to detect CSV's. In your routes.php file make sure you've set the parse extension for CSVs:-

```
Router::parseExtensions('csv');
```

Then in your controller set the filename for the CSV and make sure you're using a layout that doesn't output markup (e.g. the default ajax.ctp):-

```
$this->response->download("$csv_filename.csv");
$this->layout = 'ajax';
```

Also make sure you have `RequestHandler` in your controller's component list:-

```
public $components = array('RequestHandler');
```

You just need to put your action template in a csv directory of the controller's view.

If it still doesn't work then there is probably some markup being output that needs removing. Cake's errors can do this.

Comment: I already corrected the errors, but still it will let me download same on the first image on my question

Comment: Are you sure the file contains no HTML markup? Save the file and check the contents. Getting a CSV file working in CakePHP can be a bit of a pain if there are errors in the file. You may want to check out http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/11/21/serving-views-as-files-in-cake2/ which goes into detail the method I've suggested here for downloadable CSV files.